# How to reduce staging tasks with CI in Kentico 13

Tags: continuous-integration, kentico

I'm looking for advice on how to deal with Kentico's staging tasks as they relate to Kentico 13's continuous integration development model.

Here's our challenge:

Each developer has their own Kentico database, developing using Visual studio, git source control through Azure DevOps and the CI switch turned on in Kentico.

As the developer makes a change to a Kentico object, for example, adds a new property to a custom page type, the CI process in Kentico serializes the page type onto the file system for that developer.  They create a pull request and the new XML file that represents the serialized page type is now in source control... along with basically every other Kentico object.

When the DevOps release process kicks in, our shared build server is updated through the CIRestore process with the new page type property.  All good - everything working as expected at this point.

However, at some stage we need to get this new page type property from the shared build server into testing, and later production. And traditionally we'd using Kentico Staging to do this.  The problem we're facing is that during the CIRestore process in our build server every single Kentico object is updated regardless of whether an actual change was made... and in that list of hundreds and hundreds of items in the Staging task list is our update page type with the new property.

The issue is that we have no way of identifying what's actually changed and subsequently what needs to be staged from our build server through to the test instance of Kentico. We don't want to stage everything as there are hundreds and hundreds of items.

We've reviewed the repository.config file and have made some changes to exclude many object types. And we initially thought that we could use this approach to just include the page types (and other objects) that we want to monitor in the CI process, however this config works in an exclude manner rather than an inclusive manner. So we'd have to add an entry to exclude every object by name which seems a bit error-prone and redundant.

I'm hoping someone's been through this pain and I'm looking for suggestions on how we might handle this challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this thread on [devnet](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/ci-module-logs-everything-in-the-staging-module). You can actually write a global event handler to tell the system to not generate tasks in the staging module based on certain conditions.

You could also try excluding all objects and then using the `IncludedObjectTypes` as a whitelist for just the ones that you want. Check out this [documentation](https://docs.xperience.io/developing-websites/setting-up-continuous-integration/excluding-objects-from-continuous-integration).

In general CI does take some time to setup and get correct in our experience. This [Kentico CI cheat sheet](https://mmt-cdn-prod-media-01.azureedge.net/mediacontainer/medialibraries/mmtdigital/mmtdigital/blog/2017/october/kentico-ci-cheatsheet/kentico-ci-cheatsheet.pdf) can be helpful as well.